# Django admin ManyToManyField add button and list display

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have models:

```
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField()
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    image = FilerImageField()

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, blank=True)
```

admin.py:

```
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def thumb(self, obj):
        return '<img src=%s />' %obj.image.icons['64']
    thumb.short_description = 'Preview'
    thumb.allow_tags = True

    list_display = ('image', 'name', 'thumb', )

class CityAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('images', )

admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
admin.site.register(City, CityAdmin)
```

Questions:
1. How to add "+" button in CityAdmin above m2m widget? Currently what i have:[image]
2. Is it possible in CityAdmin m2m widget have some list display where I can see image thumbnail? Ideally like in ImageAdmin: [image]

What I have tried:

- In Image model `__unicode__` function `return '<img src=%s />' %self.image.icons['64']`, but then in admin it just displays raw text.

Comment: In both cases what you need to do is to write your custom templates for admin views, containing the desired featues.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: Sure there is no other easier way? For example, if I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/1/ there is already that "+" button. I assume django uses same template for my own apps, so there has to be way to add that button without writing my own templates.